# CouchDB - document removed by PUT _deleted attribute is still available

Tags: database, synchronization, couchdb, pouchdb

I remove document in CouchDB by setting the `_deleted` attribute to true (PUT method). The last revision of document is deleted but previous revision is still available.

And when I pull documents of specific type from database, this document is still available.

How I should delete document to not be available?

I use synchronization between CouchDB on the server and PouchDB instances on mobile applications (Ionic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compact your database. Compaction is a process of removing unused and old data from database or view index files, not unlike `vacuum` in RDBMS. It could be triggered by calling `_compact` end-point of a database, e.g. `curl -X POST http://192.168.99.100:5984/koi/_compact -H'Content-Type: application/json'`. After that the attempts to access the previous revisions of a deleted document should return error 404 with a reason `missing`.

Note that the document itself not going to completely disappear, something called "tombstone" will be left behind. The reason is that CouchDB needs to track deleted documents during replication to prevent accidental document recovery.

Comment: Thanks for fast response.

Comment: I have 2 questions:

- How offen I should do it? I read documentation but there is no written about that.

- Is it help me with situation like this: I updated document three times and when I removed doc (`PUT`, `_deleted=true`) I had previous revision of this doc. So only when I run compactiation, after removing doc I won't get previous revision?

Comment: A frequency of compaction depends on your business needs. Normally it's executed not to remove outdated documents revisions, but to reclaim space and a good rule of thumb is to run it once database riches about 70% of fragmentation, where fragmentation defined as `(file_size - data_size) / file_size * 100`. Both file size and data size could be found at `GET /db` end-point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second question. If you are asking if the old revisions will be removed only for the deleted documents, then no, compaction removes all outdated revisions, for deleted and presented documents alike. If the question if there another way to remove outdated revisions apart from compaction, then, again, not really, MVCC is integral part of Couch and base for its distributed capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. 
But happened something strange. After run _compact and _view_cleanup the database started growing up very quickly. Before this, DB had 10 MB and now it grows about 0.5 MB per minute. What I did wrong? Or maybe it is normall behaviour?

Comment: A database growth rate, naturally, depends on an update rate. If your workload didn't change and you are talking about absolute, not a relative, size growth, then it might be a sign of a document conflict. 
However this is getting out of scope of your original question, so I'd suggest to ask any maintenance follow up questions on CouchDB users mail list: user@couchdb.apache.org